# Passing reference to google places API and not getting the same back

Tags: api, google-maps

I'm trying to retrieve a latlng of a place using a reference. For some reason it is returning the wrong place to me (which actually has a different reference).

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?sensor=true&key=_API_KEY_GOES_HERE_&reference=CmRfAAAAHsCGh9j9MSeFsmUJgBlNcmzhpMgVaUfyl97WMBEKjY3U-0xjUHzGDy0DU_RQY5vn_MeGdKJ7uyFfVNC0bkaJ5uIlK0Pi0jUF9hcHmuEIFNGPWJKDRR9r1sIu7mWeCBm0EhCH8kQSAG_PRj6QQe60VoxpGhTfjf-gJzyeHQqcdBvnRgSjhvn5ow

And this is the reference that comes back, surely it should be the same?
CmReAAAAhRhvziiV503CkyTnxh8sC5ft38xdSy_7PVGMmtQudlaw5HTo1EbIL3IxkChXd4ZYr06FHI59PgybhUoZfrtGfNNzgNxBTZubxV7fAv3LpvulULuXEQYidgngU8WpwkM9EhB5PCeiQwiUKPuFaV5MHW9mGhS9FUBd1ueZ-b1ueSWeyPhA2t0c6Q

The reference points to postcode 'w5 4ep' but is returning westminster

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is version 2 of google-maps, then it is deprecated why don't you migrate to V3 that is more flexible and reliable.

Comment: It isn't any version of google maps really, it's the Places web service.

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places - but revisiting that link has lead me to their javascript implementation so I will give that a go :)

Comment: Turns out I was accidentally using the V2 like you mentioned! Presumed I was using the V3 - Cheers refhat!

Comment: I get this issue while using v3 (3.9.11b).